Evaluating $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^8-21\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)-13$
That is a problem that seemed very interesting for me, because I know the answer but I just can't reach it. So I'd like any help or hint so I could show that $$\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^8-21\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)-13=0$$

What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Hint: $x^8 = ((x^2)^2)^2$

$\phi = 1-\frac {\sqrt 5}{2}$
is a root of  $x^2 - x -1$
$\phi^2 = \phi + 1$
$\phi^n = F_{n-1} + F_n\phi$ where $F_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number.
You can prove this by induction.
$\phi^8 = 13 + 21\phi$
Plugging that into the original equation gives $0.$

This can also be proved using https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFormula.html

This question is related to the golden ratio and the Fibonacci numbers, which some of the numerical values in the question may give you a hint about. But even if you don't realise this, you can work through it by observing that the number $x = \frac{1 - \sqrt 5} 2$ is the negative root of $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$.
Rewrite as $x^2 = x + 1$
Now square, and keep reducing the right hand side to a linear expression. I'll do just the first, and leave the next step to you.
$x^4 = (x^2)^2 = (x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x + 1 = (x+1)+2x+1 = 3x+2$.
Now find $x^8$ in a similar fashion from that, and see what happens when you substitute it into the given expression.

I thought the simplest way is just working it out (although avoiding estimating the square root of 5).
This is shown through the following
simplification and working out
which states that
$$
\frac{4672-1345\sqrt{5}}{128}-13=0
$$

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!  I briefly looked at your calculations.  At the beginning you show $2^8=128$.  That is not correct.  There may be other errors.

There is at least one other error: $1344-1000-1400-280-8\neq1345$.

After correcting for those two errors, the sum comes to zero, but really this is not an easy way to do it.
